# "Stability" of time series data

Tags: time-series

I have a time series dataset and I want to explore how much the values change. The values are discrete from 1 to N levels. Given any period "chunk" from the series, I would like to calculate "how much the values change". For example, if there was only value M present in the period and no other value, then the result would be 100% = 100% stable, no changes. If there were all values from 1 to N and none of them was repeated, the result would be 0% = not stable at all. Is there any way to do this? I have no background in statistics and don't even know what to ask a search engine at this point. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: This isn't a fleshed out answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment... isn't something like variance enough (you could just normalize that variance if you specifically needed a percent)? I imagine you can google something like "measures of spread."